# make an object be clickable from behind of another element in html

Tags: html, css

take look at this:
http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/35403.html

In this template you can click on the image under the man's forearm even over the forearm itself.
The hand is not a part of images. It is three `div` pieces that has a png image as background.

How is it possible?
How Can I do the same thing (have a div that contains a linked image and have another div on it but the underlying link be clickable)?
Is it cross-browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could just add `pointer-events:none` in your stylesheet to the element you're trying to click through

Example here:  http://robertnyman.com/css3/pointer-events/pointer-events.html

Check the checkbox to see how the grey box is able to be clicked through.

Comment: this is the kind of nonsense that makes me think "damn those developers of the browsers are so smart"

Answer (score 5):

it's made with

```
pointer-events:none;
```

it don't works in IE and Opera, but that is in this case not really a problem. It just don't work over the arm itself.

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers you can use the pointer-events css3 property. Here is a famous question about this : [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)